# find values in a shuffled list of sublists by one of the values

Tags: python, list

I have a list if lists

```
items = [
    ["e",None,None],
    ["pork","pork.png","meat"],
    ["beef","b.png","meat"],
    ["cheese","c.png","not"],
    ]
items_list = ["e","beef","pork","beef"]
shuffle(items_list)
```

how can I print the second or third value in sublists without their index?

```
for i in items_list:
    print ???
```

Comment: maybe include a sample input and output. it's not really clear what you want to do here

Comment: Are you asking how to get the indexes of the sub lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your `items` sublists in a dictionary, indexed by their first elements.

```
from random import shuffle

items = [
    ["e",None,None],
    ["pork","pork.png","meat"],
    ["beef","b.png","meat"],
    ["cheese","c.png","not"],
]

items_dict = {u[0]: u for u in items}

items_list = ["e","beef","pork","beef"]
shuffle(items_list)

for s in items_list:
    print(s, items_dict[s])
```

**output**

```
beef ['beef', 'b.png', 'meat']
e ['e', None, None]
beef ['beef', 'b.png', 'meat']
pork ['pork', 'pork.png', 'meat']
```

---

To print the second items (i.e., the PNGs):

```
for s in items_list:
    print(s, items_dict[s][1])
```

**output**

```
e None
beef b.png
beef b.png
pork pork.png
```

---

This is fairly efficient since no new lists are made: the lists in `items_dict` are the same list objects that are in `items`. So if you want, you can mutate those lists either via `items` or `items_dict`.

```
items_dict["cheese"].append("cheddar")
print(items[3])

items[0][2] = "something"
print(items_dict["e"])
```

**output**

```
['cheese', 'c.png', 'not', 'cheddar']
['e', None, 'something']
```

---

You don't *need* the `items_dict`, but the alternative is a double `for` loop, which gets *very* inefficient if `items` is large.

```
for s in items_list:
    for seq in items:
        if seq[0] == s:
            print(s, seq)
            break
```

**output**

```
beef ['beef', 'b.png', 'meat']
e ['e', None, None]
beef ['beef', 'b.png', 'meat']
pork ['pork', 'pork.png', 'meat']
```

Comment: sounds simple enough, how do I go about defining my list as a dictionary at the first place? each item would be like: ['e': [None,None]], right?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
from random import shuffle

items = [
    ["e",None,None],
    ["pork","pork.png","meat"],
    ["beef","b.png","meat"],
    ["cheese","c.png","not"],
    ]

items_list = ["e","beef","pork","beef"]
shuffle(items_list)

for item in items_list:
    for orig_item in items:
        try:
            orig_item.index(item)
            print(item, orig_item)
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

Output:

```
beef ['beef', 'b.png', 'meat']
pork ['pork', 'pork.png', 'meat']
e ['e', None, None]
beef ['beef', 'b.png', 'meat']
```

This might be slower than @PM 2Ring's answer (I haven't measured) because of two loops and the exception handling.

use `orig_item[1]` to access the second element of the sublist